# How to create a Package.swift for an existing xcode project

Tags: swift

Consider a small existing project `ffttest` https://github.com/javadba/Swift-FFT-Example/tree/upgrade_swift52 . This works :

```
> Amplitude: 8.0
Frequency: 4.0
Phase: -1.1102230246251565e-15
0   0.0     -8.038073113980855e-15
1   0.7841371226364848     0.7841371226364765
2   1.560722576129026     1.5607225761290189
..
509   -2.3222774180357333     -2.3222774180357075
510   -1.5607225761290364     -1.560722576129034
511   -0.784137122636526     -0.7841371226364928
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

The program has the following directory structure:

[image]

Now I would like to add dependencies and other things traditionally performed in a `Package.swift`.  Is there a tool to build/infer it from this existing project?